# Using link-own variable to transfer resources between specific turtles

Tags: netlogo

Say we have two turtles with a link between them, and that link owns a variable that represents the age of the link, "tenure".  For turtle 1 to send resources to turtle 2, there is a conversion cost related to the age of the link between them.  How do I refer to the tenure value of the specific link between these two turtles?

In context, I have turtles linked into "households" and as they start each day they assess how much energy they have.  If they have more than some threshold of energy, they share the surplus with fellow housemates.  To elect how they will share the energy, I have them looping through each housemate to determine who has low health.  Surplus energy can be transferred to a housemate, but the conversion rate depends upon the tenure of the link between them.  A longer tenure results in a better conversion rate of energy into health.  But I don't know how to refer to the specific value of the linked-owned variable between each turtle and each of their housemates.

Right now, I have this approach of the shared-link being something like [link = [link] of myself] but that doesn't work:

```
turtles-own [energy health age]
links-own [tenure]

to go
  tick
  ask links
  [
    set tenure tenure + 1]
  ask turtles
  [
    ifelse energy > 3 [supply] [rest]]
end

to supply 
  let surplus energy - 3
  loop 
  [ask one-of link-neighbors 
    [
      let shared-link link = [link] of myself
      if health < 3 [set health  health + 1 * [log [tenure] of shared-link] 
        set surplus surplus-1]
  ]]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this snippet. it illustrates what I think you need.

```
links-own [ weight ]
to setup
  clear-all
  random-seed  12345
  create-turtles 4 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor set label who set size 3]
  ask turtles [ create-links-with other turtles [ set weight random 100 set label weight ]]
  ask turtle 1 [ ask link-with turtle 2 [ set color red set thickness 0.5  ]] 
  ask turtle 1 [ 
                   let myweight [weight ] of link-with turtle 2
                   print ( word "Turtle 1 says, my link weight with turtle 2 is " myweight )
                ]
  
  ask turtles [ ask link-neighbors [ 
                     let myweight [weight ] of link-with myself  
                    print ( word myself "  says, my link weight with " self "  is " myweight )
              ]]
    
  reset-ticks
end
```

Comment: "let myweight [weight ] of link-with myself"  <--- This is what I needed, Wade!  Thank you!